# Get message with PHP from subscribed topics automaticallyfrom cloudmqtt

Tags: php, mqtt

I am implementing mqtt with php on a web application i am currently working on. Basically, i want to publish temperature sensor data from my raspberry pi to cloudmqtt(using the paho client library), this part has been smooth. I intend to use phpmqtt to subscribe to the topic and get messages from cloudmqtt but i just remembered that the php script will never run automatically on its own and thus cannot get the messages instantly unless.

I have tried to use cron jobs to make the script run at intervals so as to get the messages at regular intervals but cron jobs only offer me 30 mins to hours intervals while i need the script to run in intervals of like 5 seconds.

I would like to know if there is a solution or a workaround for this. If not, advise on how i can do things differently will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try this https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-execute-less-than-1-minute-intervals-jobs-using-cron-time-based-scheduler

Comment: Skip the PHP entirely and just have the page it's self connect to the broker and subscribe to the topics using MQTT over Websockets and the Paho Javascript client

Comment: @JasonK How am i supposed to implement this on a web server that I don't own? It is not a private web server.

Comment: @hardillb I get your point, but then again i want to know how i can make it work with php

Comment: You said you have rpi. Is that suddenly not true?